# neo4jclient merge query cause unhandled exception

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I want to use merge in my neo4jclient c# application, so I read [this link](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples) and create a query like the below one :

```
resultList.ForEach(
tweets => client.Cypher
    .Merge("(tweet:Tweet {newtweet})")
    .OnCreate()
    .Set("tweet = {newtweet}")
    .WithParams(new Tweets(tweets))
    .ExecuteWithoutResults());
```

But it crash and I don't know what I am missing.

Which part of my code is wrong?

Comment: In the example link, it will create a new user if it does not already exist, based on the user id. Are you trying to do the same here. Should have have a tweet id? Can you post a working Cypher statement?

Comment: @OlivierDeMeulder I don't have any working Cypher ! you mean I should add my twitter Unique ID in the query ? how ?!

Comment: I assume you have a list of tweets that you're trying to enter in NEO4J. For each tweet, you probably have a unique id, the author and the tweet itself. The merge function in NEO4J allows you to update an existing node or create a new one. For that to work, you check the id of the tweet. As shown in the example in the link you provided. Is that the case?

Comment: @OlivierDeMeulder yes, the case is true, I have a statusID that I think is unique key for tweet, I want to add to my db if it doesn't exists yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define your tweet class:

```
public class Tweet {
    public long StatusId { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; } 
}
```

Then try this statement like this:

```
var newTweet = new Tweet { StatusId = 2344
    , Author = "@AuthorName"
    , Content = "this is a tweet" };
graphClient.Cypher
    .Merge("(tweet:Tweet { StatusId: {id} })")
    .OnCreate()
    .Set("tweet = {newTweet}")
    .WithParams(new {
        id = newTweet.StatusId,
        newTweet
    })
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Comment: Just worth adding that if you have a lot of tweets to go through you might find this takes some time, in which case have a look at the `Foreach` statement in Cypher, as you can probably add them all in one hit.